# Can an RC receiver antenna work for an ESP8266?

Tags: antenna, esp8266, radio

I will be building a project that uses an ESP8285 based ESP01F board (kind of ESP8266) and I need an antenna for this module. The antenna I need should be very light and thin so I thought of using an RC receiver antenna like [this one](https://robu.in/product/150mm-frsky-receiver-antenna-new-version-ipex4/), by cutting the given connector and soldering the antenna and ground cable as I have seen for some ESP8266 board modifications previously which used an SMS cable external antenna.

Will it work or I should look for another antenna (which I did and got nothing) or try making my own? I will be using it as a wifi receiver board (kind of like powerup 3) and about 100metres of range would be than enough for it in a completely open area away from residences.
Edit: I have removed that previous image of sma external antenna as I previously used it as a reference for what should be heavy for my purpose but it creates more confusion.This is what I currently have (https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtjfG.jpg)

Comment: Antenna for what purpose?

Comment: [Try searching for "ESP8285 antenna"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22ESP8285%22+antenna&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwi5psfo3eb1AhXUiP0HHZtXBncQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=%22ESP8285%22+antenna&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzIHCCMQ7wMQJ1D6EljPImCgK2gAcAB4AIABQYgBugGSAQEzmAEAoAEBqgELZ3dzLXdpei1pbWfAAQE&sclient=img&ei=yXf9YfmdLNSR9u8Pm6-ZuAc&bih=726&biw=1290&rlz=1C1CHBF_en-GBGB908GB908). There seems to be literally dozens of links and pictures so, when you say `which I did and got nothing` I am baffled`.

Comment: There are some which are too heavy for this purpose and the coil- like one's won't deliver to me.

Answer (score 1):

Look for an ESP32 or ESP8266 with a U.FL connector for an external antenna. Check upper right corner of image below.  Then look for an antenna with this same connector. This connector is commonly used for antennas inside laptops, routers, etc.  antennas are also available at electrics compnents distributors, Amazon, ebay, alibaba,...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It probably wont work and the signal will be attenuated.

Why? because the impedance needs to be controlled/matched from the ESP8266 through the PCB and to the antenna connector.

Comment: There is actually no build-in antenna on board but a seperate pin available for external antenna.

Comment: @AnmolKumar Your photo clearly shows the on-board antenna, I'm not sure what you're talking about.

Comment: I repeat, you cannot get 2.4Ghz through anything but a connector that's built for it very well

Comment: @voltage that's ignoring the countless hobby and commercial products directly soldering wire antenna instead of using connectors.

Comment: @anmol what model esp do you have. Add a picture of your actual board or find one online.

Comment: @hearth it looks like the picture he used is from an instructible where they used a d1 mini clone and cut the pcb antenna. It's confusing.

Answer (score 0):

It will work, but at some reduced efficiency or power. You are using a 2.4 GHz tuned antenna for a 2.4 GHz application. You are reducing its tuned length which throws it off a little.

Your question is using a picture of a board and antenna you don't have so we can't answer directly. The antenna you linked to has a newer super micro connector (ipex mfh 4) and you will find esp boards with an older connector (u.fl or ipex mfh 1) That connector is very very small like half a grain of rice.

The picture you use has a wire antenna to a RP mountable connector (iirc), and then the rest of the antenna is in a plastic protector. The inside is likely either a flat wire or a wire with a tight coil at some point. You can remove the plastic to make it thinner. All it does is protect the antenna from physical damage.

**Find a wire antenna with the correct connector for a esp board with a external antenna connector** for best results. Or find a wire antenna prepared for soldering.